# Textbox not showing true result when multiply double variables

Tags: c#

I am writing a code about multiplying two double variables taken from different `textboxes` and show result at another `textbox`. But I can't get right result.

My code is:

```
double mny = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxMny.Text);
double winmultiplier = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxwinmultiplier.Text);

win1 = mny * winmultiplier;

textBox1win.Text = win1.ToString();
```

I gave `mny = 0.000015` and `winmultiplier 5.21`. Textbox is displaying `7815` for result.

Comment: What's the data type of win1

Comment: are you sure it's not `7.815E-05`? Did you debugged your code?

Comment: `textBox1win.Text = $"{win1:f10}"` and `double.Parse` should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

`521*15 = 7815`, seems like C# omits the delimiters, so I think that the problem is that your system double delimiter is not `.`, try using the `,` as delimiter. Also try using the `double.Parse()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use
 `win1.ToString("0.0000000")`

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Decimal.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) especially for Text values. User may enter any good or bad value.

```
if(decimal.TryParse(..))
{
    // success
}
```

Also, try this for formatting the decimal to string:

```
String sh = a.ToString("0.0000000");
```

Answer (score 0):

Floating point value (e.g. `double`) when represented as `string` can have two kinds of delimiters: *decimal* one and thousand *separator*.
When converting / parsing from `string` thousand saparator are ignored:

```
// notice, that "thousand" sparators not necessary separate thousands
"1,12,4567,8.93" -> 11245678.93d;
```

Both *decimal* and thousand *separator* are *culture dependent*; for isntance in Russian Culture (`Ru-ru`) thousand separator is `.` and decimal is `,`:

```
"0.000015" -> 00000015d == 15d
"5.21"     -> 521d      == 521d
```

In your case, you can specify *culture*, e.g. `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` where `,` is a thousand separator, and `.` is decimal one. Another suggestion is to use `TryParse` instead of `Convert` on user input (we should react properly if user enters, say, `"bla-bla-bla"` instead of valid value)

```
using System.Globalization;

...

if (!double.TryParse(textBoxMny.Text, 
                     NumberStyles.Any, 
                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                     out double mny))
  textBox1win.Text = "Mny is not a vaid floating point value";  
else if (!double.TryParse(textBoxMny.Text, 
                          NumberStyles.Any, 
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                          out double winmultiplier))
  textBox1win.Text = "winmultiplier is not a vaid floating point value";  
else
  textBox1win.Text = (mny * winmultiplier).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```